# ¿Cómo puedo modificar en python código de un módulo de terceros que llama a un otro modulo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasa-nlu

Al ejecutar una función que prueba el [paquete rasa.nlu](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/) noté que estaba usando una función de un paquete que me lanzaba advertencias. Pero mirando bien la función, siento que las advertencias no tienen nada que ver. Esta es la función en cuestión, `train_nlu`.

```
from rasa_nlu.training_data import load_data
from rasa_nlu import config
from rasa_nlu.model import Trainer
from rasa_nlu.model import Metadata, Interpreter

def train_nlu(data, configs, model_dir):
    training_data = load_data(data)
    print("trainer:\n")
    trainer = Trainer(config.load(configs))
    print("trainer.train:\n")
    trainer.train(training_data)
    print("trainer.persist:\n")
    model_directory = trainer.persist(model_dir, fixed_model_name = 'moodnlu')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_nlu('./data/data.json', 'config_spacy.json', './models/nlu')
    run_nlu()
```

Obtengo los warnings siguientes :

```
(flaskenv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp$ python3 nlu_model.py 

trainer:

trainer.train:

Fitting 2 folds for each of 6 candidates, totalling 12 fits
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/flaskenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/flaskenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/flaskenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/flaskenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/flaskenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/flaskenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done  12 out of  12 | elapsed:    0.1s finished
trainer.persist:

/home/mike/Programming/Rasa/myflaskapp/flaskenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rasa_nlu/extractors/entity_synonyms.py:85: UserWarning: Failed to load synonyms file from './models/nlu/default/moodnlu/entity_synonyms.json'
  "".format(entity_synonyms_file))
{'text': 'I am planning my holiday to Lithuania. I wonder what is the weather out there.', 'intent_ranking': [{'confidence': 0.8355857954304632, 'name': 'inform'}, ... no es importante ...
```

Me gustaría cambiar estas advertencias

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples
```

para obtener y devolver los `intent` que no tienen sufficiente `predicted samples`.

Pero warning salen de una función [classification.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/classification.py) y no encontré la fuente?

La clase de Training y la función de `train()` están aquí:

```
class Trainer(object):
    """Trainer will load the data and train all components.

    Requires a pipeline specification and configuration to use for
    the training."""

    # Officially supported languages (others might be used, but might fail)
    SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES = ["de", "en"]

    def __init__(self,
                 cfg,  # type: RasaNLUModelConfig
                 component_builder=None,  # type: Optional[ComponentBuilder]
                 skip_validation=False  # type: bool
                 ):
        # type: (...) -> None

        self.config = cfg
        self.skip_validation = skip_validation
        self.training_data = None  # type: Optional[TrainingData]
...

def train(self, data, **kwargs):
    # type: (TrainingData) -> Interpreter
    """Trains the underlying pipeline using the provided training data."""

    self.training_data = data

    context = kwargs  # type: Dict[Text, Any]

    for component in self.pipeline:
        updates = component.provide_context()
        if updates:
            context.update(updates)

    # Before the training starts: check that all arguments are provided
    if not self.skip_validation:
        components.validate_arguments(self.pipeline, context)

    # data gets modified internally during the training - hence the copy
    working_data = copy.deepcopy(data)

    for i, component in enumerate(self.pipeline):
        logger.info("Starting to train component {}"
                    "".format(component.name))
        component.prepare_partial_processing(self.pipeline[:i], context)
        updates = component.train(working_data, self.config,
                                  **context)
        logger.info("Finished training component.")
        if updates:
            context.update(updates)

    return Interpreter(self.pipeline, context)
```

Sé que [este pregunta de stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162506/undefinedmetricwarning-f-score-is-ill-defined-and-being-set-to-0-0-in-labels-wi) puede ayudar.